# GAE datastore viewer - editing lists

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to somehow enable editing lists in GAE datastore viewer?
I'm using Python version of SDK.

Basically I want to avoid, as much as possible, writing own CRUD as it
 wouldn't be necessary if only I could edit lists in datastore viewer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not built in to the datastore viewer, no. With the 1.3.1 release of the SDK, it is possible to add custom pages to the Admin console, but that wouldn't really save you from having to write the list editing page yourself.

[AppEnngine Custom Pages Documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Administration_Console_Custom_Pages)

Comment: Thanks. I know about that custom admin pages, but couldn't have found any documentation about it - unless I'm blind it's only  mentioned in release notes.

Comment: The location of the documentation is definitely not obvious. I included a link to it in my answer. I think that a custom admin page that could provide an editable grid view of the datastore would be a supercool project, and if no one does it before I get a few of my many projects settled down, I'll make it myself.

Comment: if you ever do that project... just let me know somehow :) an open source hosted on google code would be perfect..

Comment: I have several open source project already hosted on Code, and I wouldn't use anything else. I feel this idea gnawing away at me. I might just end up working on it and delaying my other projects just a bit. It is an intriguing idea. I'll figure a way to let you know.

Comment: @AdamCrossland, have you created such project? ;)

Comment: @LA_: No, I'm sorry to say that my cool datastore plugin project hasn't yet gotten off the ground. I have a surplus of cool ideas right now, and I'm desperately trying to finish one of the big ones before I roll off onto the next. I'm sure that you understand :)

Comment: @AdamCrossland I definitely would use it also.  If someone made a better datastore viewer, I'm sure it would be widely used.  Could probably sell it.

Comment: It is one of the 8 projects that I am currently juggling, not including my actual job.